# Where am I going wrong with this proof of expected value of a geometric random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I know that the expected value of a geometrically distributed random variable is $\frac1p$ but how do we get there. This is what I got so far: $$\sum_{x=1}^\infty xP(X=x)$$ where X is the number of failures until first success. Since it's geometric we have:$$\begin{align} \sum_{x=1}^\infty xp(1-p)^{x-1}\\ \frac{p}{1-p} \sum_{x=1}^\infty x(1-p)^x\\ ....  \end{align}$$ How do we sum that?

Comment: Differentiate a well-known series.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set $r=1-p$ and recall geometric [series formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)
$$
\sum\limits_{x=1}^\infty r^x=\frac{r}{1-r}
$$
Then 
$$
\sum\limits_{x=1}^\infty x r^x=
r\sum\limits_{x=1}^\infty x r^{x-1}=
r\sum\limits_{x=1}^\infty  \frac{d}{dr} r^x=
r \frac{d}{dr}\sum\limits_{x=1}^\infty r^x=
r\frac{d}{dr}\frac{r}{1-r}
$$
Is the rest clear?

Comment: then wouldn't we have $\sum_{x=1}^\infty xr^x$? How do we take care of the extra x?

Comment: Oh sorry, i'll fix it

Comment: I'm a little confused isn't r a constant ? if so then the derivative w.r to x will be r^x * ln r, right ?

Comment: @Oleg you can regard these equalities as r is a variable.

Answer (score 7):

An experiment has probability of success $p\gt 0$, and probability of failure $1-p$. We repeat the experiment until the first success. Let $X$ be the total number of trials. We want $E(X)$.

Do the experiment once. So we have used $1$ trial. If this trial results in success (probability: $p$), then the expected number of further trials is $0$. If the first trial results in failure (probability: $1-p$), our experiment has been wasted, and the expected number of trials remains at $E(X)$. Thus 
$$E(X)=1+(p)(0)+(1-p)E(X).$$
**If** $E(X)$ exists, we can solve for $E(X)$ and obtain $E(X)=\dfrac{1}{p}$.

Comment: I like the insight you made, but can you tell me why 1 isn't multiplied by $p$? since $E[X]= \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x(Pr(X=k))$?

Comment: We could do it your way. With probability $p$ we get $X=1$ (giving a term $p$, or with probability $1-p$, $E(X)=1+E(X)$. That gives $E(X)=p+(1-p)(1+E(X))$, giving exactly the same thing for $E(X)$ as was obtained in (I think) a marginally simpler way.

Comment: let me try to see if I follow with what you are doing. Are you evaluating the summation by parts? meaning $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^1 1(Pr(X=1))?$     and than representing the other half of the sum as E[X]?

Comment: The argument uses **conditional expectation**, conditioning on the first outcome. In this example, it can also be viewed as a summation trick or technique.

Comment: so its the probability of success p + the probability of failure 1-p times the expected value if we fail the 1st trial 1 + E [X]. if I got the logic down.

Comment: can we use the same logic to show that for the first success to occur it is p/q?

Comment: You my prefer to express the equation in my post as $E(X)=(p)(1)+(1-p)(1+E(X))$. Then the conditional expectation nature will be clearer. By the way, my $X$ is not the same as OP's, my $X$ is the number of trials until and including the first success. If we want the mean number of **failures** before first success, the answer is $\frac{q}{p}$.